# why dataTable is not acting if a new row with header is added

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am able to create `dataTable`  successfully

Here is **Demo**:https://jsfiddle.net/w2nevcca/3/

The problem occurs when i add

```
        <tr>
            <th class="widthind">14/11/2017</th>
        </tr>     
                 <!-- added as date divider -->
```

When i add above `code` as `divider` to show my `date`

**Here is 2nd** **Demo(Not Working)**:https://jsfiddle.net/pkxmnh2a/12/

below is my code

**HTML:**

```
<div class="table-content table-responsive">
    <table id="examples" class="display tvalues" cellspacing="0" width="100%" name="tabel">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <!--th>ID</th-->
                <th>User Id</th>
                <th>User Name</th>
                <th>Project Name</th>
                <th>Work Description</th>
                <!--<th>Reported On</th>-->
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <!--th>ID</th-->
                <th>User Id</th>
                <th>User Name</th>
                <th>Project Name</th>
                <th>Work Description</th>
                <!-- <th>Reported On</th>-->
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th class="widthind">14/11/2017</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>9cbc6e5a99bf96a61e5fa0445315286f</td>
                <td>arjun</td>
                <td>today's day report</td>
                <td>
                    <p>this my first day report employeee 2222</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>9cbc6e5a99bf96a61e5fa0445315286f</td>
                <td>arjun</td>
                <td>today's day report</td>
                <td>
                    <p>this my first day report employeee 33333</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>9cbc6e5a99bf96a61e5fa0445315286f</td>
                <td>arjun</td>
                <td>today's day report</td>
                <td>
                    <p>this my first day report employeee 44444</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="widthind">13/11/2017</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>9cbc6e5a99bf96a61e5fa0445315286f</td>
                <td>arjun</td>
                <td>yesterday report</td>
                <td>
                    <p>this my yesterday day report employeee 2222</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>9cbc6e5a99bf96a61e5fa0445315286f</td>
                <td>arjun</td>
                <td>yesterday report</td>
                <td>
                    <p>this my yesterday day report employeee 33333</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

below is my javascript code

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#examples').DataTable();
        $('a.toggle-vis').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var column = table.column($(this).attr('data-column'));
            column.visible(!column.visible());
        });

        $('#examples tfoot th').each(function () {
            var title = $('#examples thead th').eq($(this).index()).text();
            $(this).html('<input tyepe="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '"/>');
        });
        table.columns().eq(0).each(function (colIdx) {
            $('input', table.column(colIdx).footer()).on('keyup change', function () {
                table
                        .column(colIdx)
                        .search(this.value)
                        .draw();
            });
        });
    });
```

The above code works perfectly when i don't add divider to dive the date

when i add the divider the above code doesn't  work.

Please help me thanks in advance !!!!

Comment: i don't understand why people is giving `down vote` for a **real problem**

Comment: If you make sure that the additonal rows have the correct number of cells (`colspan` won't work here), you will get rid of the JS error that is preventing DataTables from rendering: https://jsfiddle.net/n34vbnmd/1/ However: How is DataTables supposed to know how to handle those rows when sorting? A better solution would be to insert those rows dynamically after each rendering - let me see if I can come up with a quick solution...

Comment: @Icepickle, rubbish, I have posted literally hundreds of "anonymous" fiddles in 4 or 5 years, none of them have ever been removed.

Comment: @EaB, agree. People can use a downvote to lay pressure on the poster, but as soon the question is edited the downvote should be changed to an upvote.

Comment: @davidkonrad, thank you very much for your support, indeed i needed that one

Comment: @Icepickle the desired behaviour should be clear: Having the DataTables plugin work and display the header rows. In the second fiddle, a JS error is preventing it from running, so it should be obvious that the OP needs a fix for this.

Comment: @Connum Personally, I don't like the fact that one has to move around between jsfiddles and the question to read everything in one go. This site has snippets, why not include those snippets here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look into the console of your browser's developer tools (open up by hitting F12 on your keyboard), you can see that there's a JavaScript error. This is in fact what's preventing DataTables from rendering.

The reason for this error is that DataTables isn't prepared to encounter such a row - it expects all rows to hold data in the same format (and the same amount of columns).

While you can get rid of the error by inserting three empty `<th>` cells to the header row (`colspan` won't work here) and thus get DataTable to render (see https://jsfiddle.net/n34vbnmd/1) - how is DataTables supposed to know how to handle those rows when sorting?

A better solution would be to insert those rows dynamically after each rendering. You'll need to group the rows that should have a common header line, for example with a custom data-attribute. Then you can use the `fnDrawCallback` callback via DataTable's options in order to generate those header rows whenever the DataTable has been redrawn.

You might also want to look into the official docs for "row grouping":
https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html - I just found this, but it's essentially doing the same as my example. Mind that I haven't tested my example thoroughly with multiple pages etc., where the code provided in the docs seems to handle this better!

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $('#examples').DataTable({
        "fnDrawCallback": function() {
          var currentGroup = null;
          $(this).find('tbody tr').each(function() {
            var thisRow = $(this),
                rowGroup = thisRow.attr('data-group');
            if (rowGroup != currentGroup) {
                currentGroup = rowGroup;
                thisRow.before('<tr class="widthind"><th colspan="4">' + rowGroup + '</th></tr>');
            }
          });
        }
    });
    
    $('a.toggle-vis').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var column = table.column($(this).attr('data-column'));
        column.visible(!column.visible());
    });

    $('#examples tfoot th').each(function () {
        var title = $('#examples thead th').eq($(this).index()).text();
        $(this).html('<input tyepe="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '"/>');
    });
    
    table.columns().eq(0).each(function (colIdx) {
        $('input', table.column(colIdx).footer()).on('keyup change', function () {
            table
                .column(colIdx)
                .search(this.value)
                .draw();
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.widthind th {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<div class="table-content table-responsive">
    <table id="examples" class="display tvalues" cellspacing="0" width="100%" name="tabel">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <!--th>ID</th-->
                <th>User Id</th>
                <th>User Name</th>
                <th>Project Name</th>
                <th>Work Description</th>
                <!--<th>Reported On</th>-->
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <!--th>ID</th-->
                <th>User Id</th>
                <th>User Name</th>
                <th>Project Name</th>
                <th>Work Description</th>
                <!-- <th>Reported On</th>-->
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr data-group="14/11/2017">
                <td>9cbc6e5a99bf96a61e5fa0445315286f</td>
                <td>arjun</td>
                <td>today's day report</td>
                <td>
                    <p>this my first day report employeee 2222</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr data-group="14/11/2017">
                <td>9cbc6e5a99bf96a61e5fa0445315286f</td>
                <td>arjun</td>
                <td>today's day report</td>
                <td>
                    <p>this my first day report employeee 33333</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr data-group="14/11/2017">
                <td>9cbc6e5a99bf96a61e5fa0445315286f</td>
                <td>arjun</td>
                <td>today's day report</td>
                <td>
                    <p>this my first day report employeee 44444</p>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr data-group="13/11/2017">
                <td>9cbc6e5a99bf96a61e5fa0445315286f</td>
                <td>arjun</td>
                <td>yesterday report</td>
                <td>
                    <p>this my yesterday day report employeee 2222</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr data-group="13/11/2017">
                <td>9cbc6e5a99bf96a61e5fa0445315286f</td>
                <td>arjun</td>
                <td>yesterday report</td>
                <td>
                    <p>this my yesterday day report employeee 33333</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```